# Webcam emulator for mac os

Tags: macos, webcam, virtual-webcam

There's a program for windows called [Fake Webcam](http://www.fakewebcam.com/Demo.asp) that allows you to show a movie as though it is data your webcam is recording.

Is there something similar for Mac OS X?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an apps, namely, [CamCamX](http://b-l-a-c-k-o-p.com/CamCamX.html)

> CamCamX allows you to take a
>   prerecorded QuickTime movie and
>   "broadcast" it as if it were a live
>   feed coming from your iSight (or other
>   webcam). CamCamX is compatible with
>   most webcam chat programs, including
>   Skype, Yahoo Messenger and iChat.

Comment: any alternates?

Comment: you could look here: http://alternativeto.net/software/manycam-virtual-webcam/ and search for "mac" in the page